# split a BigInteger into predefined size chunks

Tags: split, arrays, biginteger

i'm quite noob, self-educated java programmer, i'm trying to split a Biginteger which's length is 194 (calculated via myBigInt.toByteArray.length) in an array of BigIntegers, with every element of the array is long 7 bytes. I first tried to translate my BigInteger into a string but when it's a string i can just divide into "char-length" size and not Byte size. 
I've read about the System.arraycopy() and arraycopy of range but or i don't understand how to use em, or those functions don't fit for my case.

Actually i'm stuck with a byte[]  conversion of my BigInteger done via MyBigInt.toByteArray. Can some1 help me?

Here's an example of what i have to do:

My BigInteger: 123456789012345678901234567890 splitted into let's say chunks of 7 bytes:

```
MyBigInteger[0]=123467
MyBigInteger[1]=890123
MyBigInteger[2]=456789
```

and so on... where the MyBigInteger[0] is long 7 bytes, second one too, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really need to go with the byte[] based approach (I tried it but it didn't give the expected results), so maybe go with the char-based one which returns your example output:

```
public static BigInteger[] splitIntoParts(BigInteger value, int partLength) {
    // use the BigInteger value as string (might not work with negative values)
    String valueStr = value.toString();
    // calculate number of result parts (array length)
    int partCount = valueStr.length() / partLength;
    if (partCount * partLength < valueStr.length()) {
        // as the partCount is cut (e.g. 13/5=2) we need an extra element then
        partCount = partCount + 1;
    }
    // result data
    BigInteger[] splitted = new BigInteger[partCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        // calculate end position
        int endPos = (i + 1) * partLength;
        // if the end position exceeds the string length, then use end position of string
        if (endPos > valueStr.length()) {
            endPos = valueStr.length();
        }
        // create the part using substring
        String valuePart = valueStr.substring(i * partLength, endPos);
        // and make a BigInteger with this string
        splitted[i] = new BigInteger(valuePart);
    }
    // return result
    return splitted;
}
```

*edit:*
This is the code above, modified to work with the byte data, but I'm not sure that it returns the values you're expecting.

```
public static BigInteger[] splitIntoParts(BigInteger value, int partLength) {
    byte[] valueBytes = value.toByteArray();
    // calculate number of result parts (array length)
    int partCount = valueBytes.length / partLength;
    if (partCount * partLength < valueBytes.length) {
        // as the partCound is cut (e.g. 13/5=2) we need an extra element then
        partCount = partCount + 1;
    }
    // result data
    BigInteger[] splitted = new BigInteger[partCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        // calculate end position
        int endPos = (i + 1) * partLength;
        // if the end position exceeds the value length, then use end position
        if (endPos > valueBytes.length) {
            endPos = valueBytes.length;
        }
        // create a buffer for the part and fill it
        byte[] valuePart = new byte[endPos - i * partLength];
        System.arraycopy(valueBytes, i, valuePart, 0, valuePart.length);
        // and make a BigInteger with this part
        splitted[i] = new BigInteger(valuePart);
    }
    // return result
    return splitted;
}
```

Comment: First of all thx for the time u spent solving my problem :) But i have a question. The valueStr.length() give the number of characters of the string, not the number of bytes :/

Comment: Yes, that's right, because the solution works on the string parts. If you really need to work with the byte chunks, then you should check if the expected result (1234567, 8901234, ...) is correct, because when splitting a number like you gave as an example byte-chunk-wise, then you'd get a very different chunk result. If needed, update your question accordingly.

Comment: edited, actually i'm trying with streams but still no solution :(

Comment: Provided a version working on `byte[]` data but not sure that it returns the values you're expecting.

Comment: Unluckily it does not work as intended :( I think actually that's not possible to do so. I'm trying to do it by putting the BigInteger into a file, split the file, and then translate the files into strings into BigInteger. It actually works but it sucks as concept :/